# Is it possible to detect which deprecated classes are actively used?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a relatively complex java project, with many classes that are probably not used.

Static analysis of the code base is relevant for some of the classes, but some are loaded dynamically (network services, persisted data, etc.)

Is there a method to get a list of deprecated classes that were actively used in the jvm, so I can know if those classes are used?

[I know there may be "sleeper classes" that are used only rarely, but that's a risk I can take]

Comment: The annotation is retained at runtime. Perhaps write an aspect that logs access to any matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM may have an option to print information about all used classes. For example:

```
java -verbose:class ...
```

You still would have to filter out the deprecated ones by some other means.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compile with -deprecation (or -Xlint:deprecation) to see the uses of deprecated APIs if you have to sourcecode (I guess you have it)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well, it does. If you compile with this flag the compiler will tell you not only that you are using deprecated APIs but also which of them and where. I don't understand why you think your solution if better at all as it requires an exceptional amount of try&error and will probably let to undesired behaviors in production if the testing is not completely exhaustive

Answer (score 1):

I could think of the following :

Add static initializer to each of your classes in the form

static {

// here you can get creative :

// either do some writing to a file with each class printing its name

// or do System.err outputing the class name, then later fetching the entire output.

}

If you are too lazy to manually add the piece of code you could write simple program to append this initializer to all files ending with .java.

This is simple way of getting a list of all the classes that are being used ( I think). 
Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are tools like [UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/) which I've used in the past. But that requires manual assessments which can be painful for large projects. You can do text analysis like below:

### Listing active usage deprecated methods

For static code analysis, list down deprecated methods of which source is already available using an IDE.

1. In Eclipse, goto **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Deprecated and restricted API** : Set level to `WARNING` and check the items besides.
2. In Problems view, click the down button near the tab -> **Group By -> Java Problem Type**
3. You will be able to see `Deprecation` usage list grouped together, copy the contents as text, which you can use to further prepare scripts/excel for analysis
4. Use a simple text editor to find and replace "`from the type` " and " `is deprecated`" with tab characters
5. Copy the contents to a spreadsheet. You will have a list of classes which contain deprecated methods but have active usage.

### Listing inactive usage deprecated methods

1. List down the class and method names by using similar approach above (For method name replace the text "`The method` " and " `from the type` " with tab characters).
2. This list minus the previous list is the inactive methods list.

### Listing dynamic deprecated methods

For dynamic code using reflections etc, there is no single bullet approach. You can do filtering of basic stuff using the method names.

1. List down the method names by using similar approach above (Replace the text "`The method` " and " `from the type` " with tab characters).
2. For the unique set of method names, loop to use a grep script. This type of search can be slow even for small projects. But just in case you 'ld want to invest the time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove them all and try to run your application. Every time you get a `ClassNotFoundException` for one of them, write it down and add the class back. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: I'm looking for a safer method - get the indication the class is used without effecting the actual execution

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if he used -`java -verbose:class` to check what all classes have been loaded and then write a small java program to check for `@deprecated` for all the loaded classes ?